# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 104: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with my code, so i want to print my csv file to console and it looks like this:

```
| ID  |   Tweet                                         |Prediction | System|   
|-----+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------|
| 01  |I had seen a movie "Rugrats" thats so funny�    | Positif   |Positif| 
| 02  |Incredibles 2 was amazingly amazing �           | Positif   |Positif|
```

I used tabular data to make the table so this is my code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate    
with open("file.csv","rb") as data:
                x = csv.reader(data)
                docs = []
                for i in x:
                    docs.append(i)
                    print tabulate([i], headers=['ID', 'Tweet', 'Prediction', 'System'])
```

I think the problem is the ascii `�` but i used `i.decode('utf-8','ignore')` and it not work. so my expectation in output console is like this:

```
| ID  |   Tweet                                         |Prediction | System|   
|-----+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------|
| 01  |I had seen a movie "Rugrats" thats so funny      | Positif   |Positif| 
| 02  |Incredibles 2 was amazingly amazing              | Positif   |Positif|
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

could you please try:

```
with codecs.open( "file.csv", 'rb', encoding='utf-8' ) as data :
```

otherwise just filter out all characters from your data, that's are not ASCII:

```
data = [i for i in data if ord(i) < 128]
```

Comment: @JFroz care to elaborate? what exactly did you try and what results did you get?

Comment: I got this `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 109: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @JFroz I gave you two different approaches, if the first does not work, try the second one.